# How to display all session info stored in database (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, laravel-5

Is there anyway to display all sessions data ?

I tried this way

```
 Session::all();
```

but it return current user info not all stored sessions

Then I tried this code

```
DB::table('sessions')->get();
```

it retrieve all stored data but everything is encrypted like this

```
  [id] => zZLNtqmennbg3gdsfdsffdstlvdZfjKtzZTP7Or6Tk
  [user_id] => 
  [ip_address] => 196.144.136.233
  [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G610F Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
  [payload] => YTozOntzOjY6Il90b2tlbiI7czo0MDoiOVJXSmdkZlFnVktNU3lVVlBQSFdKOElrRFFMVEdtYUJnMENiQzY4NSI7czo5OiJfcHJldmldfdsfdsfdfzOiJ1cmwiO3M6MzM6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXJldmlld3NhcHAuY29tL2Vycm9yXzQwNCI7fXM6NjoiX2ZsYXNoIjthOjI6e3M6Mzoib2xkIjthOjA6e31zOjM6Im5ldyI7YTowOnt9fX0=
  [last_activity] => 1535513730
```

Also I don't have user_id  since I use custom sessions

This code returns the correct data but for one user only

```
 Session::all();
```

How can I retrieve all sessions data  like this  ?

```
  ["plan_type"]=> string(7) "test" ["shop"]=> string(36) "test.test.com"
```

Because what stored in database is encrypted   I want user data so I know how many session each user have

Comment: what do you mean by saying "custom sessions"?

Comment: I don't use auth   for login in  I use my custom  table   so  I don't use  user table  so there's no user id associated with the session

Comment: got it. And you need to get that the user_id of the session, correct?

Comment: Also I don't realy understand what you need to get.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: as you said before there is no association between `sessions` and `users` tables, that is why there is no `user_id`.
please `dd(auth()->guard())` and if you don't use user table please `implement` those interfaces in your own table `AuthenticatableContract,    AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract`
you can see example of it in the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make your own model and reference the same table

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomSession extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sessions';
}
```

Use it as any other model... `CustomSession::all();`

As for the decryption, you can do it like this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/accessing-the-session-payload-as-a-json-object

```
$payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload)); // At this point you have an array
```

Of course you would have to do it on for and then you can assign it like

```
   foreach($sessions as $session){
       $session->payload = unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
   }
```

And as the comments in the link say:

```
// If you want an object instead, you could typecast it to a stdObject.
// $payload = (object) unserialize(base64_decode($session->payload));
```

So then you can use it as

```
$session->payload->someSome;
```

Comment: Sorry but is there any difference from this code ? DB::table('sessions')->get();   I can get all sessions from the table but in encrypted from  I can't use them   how can  I get the info from them

Comment: Not really, havent seen that line of your question, let me complement my answer with the decryption part

Comment: Thank you very much that what I looking for   it did't know it's just base64